# Using Jprofiler with Wildfly10 on remote machine(Linux)

Tags: jprofiler, wildfly-10

I need to use jprofiler along with wildfly 10.
I want to know how to attach jprofiler while starting wildfly.

I tried searching but havent got any related links.
Please can someone tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the JProfiler GUI, invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration

and follow the steps in the wizard.